# jqwidgets-datetimeinput date format d MMMM yyyy not displayed correctly

Tags: jqwidget

I am using jqwidgets-datetimeinput to display and input formatted date. It is working fine for most of the use cases but for the format `d MMMM yyyy` it is not behaving correctly.

it is showing as `6/11/2020 June 2020` instead of `11 June 2020`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I think you just found one of the many bugs/"features" that plague jqWidgets.

Upon further investigation, this seems to happen when `d` is the end of the format string, or is followed by a space character. To get around this, you can use a non-breaking space:

`'d\u00a0MMMM yyyy'`

If you're on Windows, you can also do `Alt+0160` to type it out, but this may be unwise, as the two characters look identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Calculuswhiz did the same unicode things for now